# Uncovering bubbles text using Smartdiagram

Tags: beamer, smartdiagram, uncover

I'm using Smartdiagram package to create a bubble diagram. I want to use \uncover to make multiple slides to explain each bubble. I've tried following code. It works but I'm getting a an error of missing tikz semicolon and I can't find a way around it. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{%
                Center,%
                \uncover<2>{Bubble 1},% 
                \uncover<3>{Bubble 2},%
                \uncover<4>{Bubble 3},%
                \uncover<5>{Bubble 4},%
                \uncover<6>{Bubble 5}%
                }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is obviously related to `\uncover`. You may want to use the following instead:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\smartdiagramanimated[bubble diagram]
{Center, A, B, C, D, E, F, G}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here is the third slide: 
[image]

In case you really want to show each bubble only once you might copy the command `\smartdiagramanimated` of http://www.ctan.org/pkg/smartdiagram and apply some small changes or you might want to ask the package author https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/13304/claudio-fiandrino to add this functionality. I have not tried it but the key might be `<\adv->`.